# How to share folders and how to mount flash drives on Mac OS X virtual machine using Virtualbox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, mac, macosx, virtualbox-networking

I have searched literally the whole Internet.I found pretty much ..... nothing!
The problem with details :

VirtualBox installed on Ubuntu 12.04.
I created a virtual machine to run Mac OS X Lion.

I downloaded the VirtualBox-Addition-Guest.iso and now it is located in /usr/share/virtualbox folder.I managed to use it on Backtrack 5 R3.So there is no question/doubt about the functionality of the .iso.

1) I am trying to mount a Sandisk flash drive 8 GB (FAT 32) on the guest machine on Virtualbox,which is the Mac OS X Lion.I installed the Virtualbox Extension Pack and the I chose the Mac OS X and I opened the Settings of the Virtual Machine.After going to the USB tab on the left I checked the USB Controller option and I pressed Add Filter From Device (it's the little icon on the right which illustrates a usb and a green cross).After pressing that it ways that there are no devices to add.(WHY??????) 
I did also the same thing with the USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller,but guess what.....still the same with the aforementioned!

2)I am trying to share a folder from Ubuntu to Mac OS X.Again I went to settings and I chose the Shared tabs on the left.I added a folder,I checked Auto-mount and I left unchecked the Read-Only option,but again I can't see it when I run Mac OS X.

I had an idea to add to the shared folders the /media folder in order Mac OS X to see the USB Flash Drive,but still nothing.

The only thing that I have succeed in is that I have exceed my frustration limits.

So,is there a way to solve these issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to install Oracle Virtualbox, not the OSE version from repository.

After that is installed and functional, you should NOT have to download the ISO.  Just browse to the top of your VM screen and select install guest additions:
[image]

Note that server is the only supported Mac OS guest [reference](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes).  But guest additions DO work for server edition.

With that set up, USB passthrough should work.  Then just select a device for passthrough (in this case your thumbdrive).

Before you power on the guest, go to the Settings tab of that guest in VirtualBox and click on USB:

[image]

Select Enable USB Controller and Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller and click on OK:
Using USB Devices In The Guest

Now plug in your USB device (e.g. your USB flash drive) and select it from that menu, then unplug and replug it, just to be safe.

[image]

Last, boot your VM and it should treat it like a native USB device.  If it doesn't also install the extension pack.

Comment: No I haven't installed the ose version.But I have noticed in your screenshots that the icon of your Virtualbox is different from yours.What version have you installed?

Comment: i'm one revision old i think, but it's oracle vbox.

Comment: I installed virtualbox from software center.Do not do that!I followed [**this**](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/) procedure and boom I got the right version and everything runs smooth now.Thanks aking1012 for your valuable help!

Comment: yeah, the version from software center is OSE like i guessed in chat

Comment: This might be embarrassing,but OSE stands for Open Source Edition or not?

Comment: yes, yes it does.  oracle really should put a little effort in to getting the oracle jvm and oracle vbox in to partner repositories...just saying.

Comment: You are absolutely right!I wish they do it soon.